# Create continous or neverending scrolling effect in webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is what I am thinking:

I have long web page and when the user reaches the end, I don't want the scrolling to stop just then, but I want to reload the page again from the bottom and continue the scrolling.

**Detailed**

As the user scrolls to the bottom, I want the top of the website to be removed from the top and placed at the bottom in a smooth way and this effect has be vice versa also. I mean if user scrolls up at the top of the page, then the footer must load at the top and continue in this fashion.

Comment: no idea how to do it, but maybe viewing source at slashdot.org could help you out. their main page does exactly what you're describing

Comment: You want the functionality like in twitter and facebook?? where as and when we reach at end of the page its reload the further data on same page with scrolling ..

Comment: If I'm following you, you want the user to scroll through, say, paragraphs 1...10 then instead of hitting the end of the page.... you want paragraph 1..10 to scroll into view, yes?

Comment: Umm... why?

Either way, you can grab the body innerHtml from the DOM and append it to Body to repeat the page. Is that what you are intending?

Comment: @hal, plain appending is not the problem, as the user scrolls to the bottom, I want the top of the website to be removed from the top and placed at the bottom. This effect has be vice versa also. I mean if user scrolll up and the top of the page, then the footer must load at the top

Comment: @Starx I still think you will at least need two copies of the body to handle the transition correctly. Append when they hit the bottom and prepend when they hit the top. If you are worried about DOM size, then just store a position queue and delete the non-visible body copies. I suppose you could one body, but if you delete the top, I believe you will automatically scroll the viewport back to the top because there is no content left to display.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, [Infinite Scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/) can do this. There is also a [jQuery plugin](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/).

Now whether you *should* do this... that's an entirely different question. Personally I find this behaviour extremely annoying.

Comment: It's especially annoying if I'm trying to reach the footer! :(

Comment: no no this is not what i want. I want to reload the same page and start scrolling the same page again

Comment: Google started doing it too, on Google images.

Comment: You can use the jQuery plugin to load the original page, and append it to the current.